# Warning : session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent even after using session_start() and ob_start()

Tags: php, session

I have included `Session_start() and ob_start()`; in my login page and still getting error Warning:

> session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already
>   sent (output started at ) on line 3.

I don't know what is the problem.

I tried placing `ob_start` on first line and on second line same with the `Session_start.`

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
session_start();
ob_start();

error_reporting(0);

if(!empty($_SESSION["admin_prince"])){
    header("location:../index.php"); 
}
include '../connection.php';

 ?>
```

Comment: In your actual code do you have the space before the `<?php`?

Comment: try not using PHP end tags if you're dealing with back-end application logic, this may add white-space which sends content to the browser and hence the headers cannot be modified anymore after any contents has been sent.

Comment: <?php
@ob_start();
session_start();
?> try this code in header

Comment: @chris85 yes there is space in php code before session_start()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know, if your code is well formatted in your question. But if so, remove the blank space before `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php session_start(); ?> 
<?php
ob_start();

error_reporting(0);

if(!empty($_SESSION["admin_prince"])){
    header("location:../index.php"); 
}
include '../connection.php';

 ?>
```

Comment: That didn't work same Errors

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
ob_start();

error_reporting(0);

if(!empty($_SESSION["admin_prince"])){
    header("location:../index.php"); 
}
include '../connection.php';

 ?>
```

try this.